# Trying to count a manager only once

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am sort of stuck.  I am trying to figure out this. I have created a more complex one at work, but this last part is really sticking me. We have listing of employees, and then different level of managers associated with those employees, from the CEO all the way down to direct manager. I am trying to figure out how to count the number of employees based off of manager they have. Right now, based on the cell value (Look Up this Manager or F2) it is counting the number of that manager showing up in =COUNTIF(B2:B6,F2)+COUNTIF(C2:C6,F2)+COUNTIF(D2:D6,F2)... but if they are both the direct manager and high level manager, it will double count them.
[The Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emfmJ.png)

How can I do a count, based off a cell, but only once per row, if that makes sense.

I want it to only count the manager once, even if they are listed a couple times.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options for Office 365:

`=SUM(N(BYROW(B2:D6,LAMBDA(ζ,SUM(N(ζ=F2))))>0))`

`=SUM(N(MMULT(N(B2:D6=F2),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:D6),,,0))>0))`

Comment: Nice and short formulas. But they will give a wrong answer if looking for Will's underlings. The formulas will give 3 instead of 2: Tank and Ed.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation doesn't say if you want to count direct underlings or total ones (down the chain of command). I assume that you want to count only the direct subordinates:

```
=COUNTA(LET(
myWorkers, TOCOL(A2:C6),
myManagers, TOCOL(B2:D6),
filteredRelations,DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(myWorkers, myManagers), (myWorkers <> myManagers) * (myWorkers <> 0) * (myManagers <> 0) * (myWorkers <> "") * (myManagers <> ""))), , 1),
FILTER(filteredRelations,filteredRelations=F2)))
```

How it works:

1. I create 2 lists of all workers and their managers (some are managers of nothing or themselves): TOCOL
2. I combine those 2 columns side by side: HSTACK
3. I filter out all cases where the manager is managing himself (e.g. Will/Will) or manager of nothing (Bill on D2)
4. I eliminate duplicates from this list (e.g. Ed/Will)
5. I eliminate the column of workers (filteredRelationships)
6. I filtered and counted the manager from F2.